# Wordpress Post HTML Form Submit And Get Data To Other Page Where It Receive Data And Download File

Tags: wordpress

I am making a website in which i will write different articles on my website templates. I want that the form of post page

```
<form id="downloadForm" action="https://getintopc.software/wait-for-resource-to-download" method="post" target="_blank">
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="https://getintopc.s3.amazonaws.com">
<input name="filename" type="hidden" value="newsplus-news-and-magazine-wordpress-theme-2023-01-17-09-54-35-utc.zip">
<input name="filesize" type="hidden" value="15.5 MB">
<p></p>
<div align="center">
<button class="btn" title="Size: 15.5 MB">Download 64 Bit x64</button>
</div>
</form>
```

https://getintopc.software/wait-for-resource-to-download
Opens And File Download This file has php code but it is not working

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['filename'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $filename = $_POST['filename'];
    $filesize = $_POST['filesize'];
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);
    readfile($id . '/' . $filename);
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Invalid form data.";
}
```

}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the button. You used general button tag:

```
<button>
```

And this will not send the form.

To send the forum you need submit button, and syntax for it looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="click me!" />
```

But probably you overcomplicated your code, as if you will run this, you will be redirected to provided page, and your page (where user clicked the button) will be not accessible. Maybe a simple hyperlink will do the trick here?

```
<a href="https://getintopc.s3.amazonaws.com/<?php echo $filename; ?>" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```

With this PHP code inside, you can keep file name in variable and reuse this code for different files, just by replacing variable. With target _blank, it will be opened in new tab, and ZIP should be automatically downloaded.

If there is no hidden motive for using form, this will be much simpler and shorter solution.